# Quantos pontos são "muitos pontos" para um usuário removido?

Tags: suporte, votos, duvida, pontos

Lembro de já ter lido por aqui que quando um usuário é removido os pontos dos votos dados por ele são removidos. Até ai tudo bem, mas me parece também que ***quando esse usuário já deu muitos votos na comunidade os pontos desses votos são mantidos na comunidade***.

Pois então, quantos são esses "Muitos Votos"? Qual é o limite que o usuário tem que votar para os pontos continuarem na comunidade?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O strike: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?page=4534&tab=reputation&filter=week

Comment: Não sei se esse valor é divulgado, existe um post de 2015 no [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268608/818993) dizendo que `Os valores exatos desses limites não importam particularmente; eles são muito baixos, mas não tão baixos que você possa atingi-los facilmente enquanto oculta atividades fraudulentas.`

Comment: Isso é uma fator que deveria mudar na minha opinião, o cara se desdobra a mil, faz a resposta ganha pontuação e porque o cara saiu os pontos são removidos, mas, a pergunta existe e pode e deve ser utilizada como fonte. Isso realmente eu não entendo e não acho válido, são muitos coisas que deveriam mudar essa é uma.